# How to hide / remove youtube play button from youtube embed player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using YouTube embed player. I want to hide /remove YouTube's default play button so that I can show my own custom play button. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can have your own custom play button that sits outside the video area; however, you cannot remove YouTube's play button or put your own button on top of the video ... to do so would violate the terms of service of the API.

Answer (score 0):

At least when using the iFrame method (according to [this docs entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#controls)), there is the `controls` option, which lets you choose whether to show player controls or not.

I am not sure if it works with HTML5, though.

@jlmcdonald: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if it's officially supported and documented, why would it violate the terms of service?